# Как организовать систему резервного хранения данных?

Tags: svn, резервное-копирование

Добрый день.
После шифрования вирусом всех важных файлов на компьютерах фирмы встал вопрос о поднятии системы резервного хранения данных... Сначала я хотел использовать тот же акронис и создавать им полные образы жестких дисков, но тут мне сказали, что надо бы "сэкономить"... Вот сижу и думаю, можно ли для этого приспособить SVN? Отсюда возникает ряд вопросов:
Как он хранит свои данные?
Можно ли сжать репозитарий и отчистить совсем уж устаревшие ревизии для экономии места?
Если делать удобную управляемую обвязку для SVN.exe, svnadmin.exe, svnserve.exe, то как быть с заблокированными файлами? (Пробовал уже добавить все содержимое диска, но при попытке прочитать корзину выдает ошибку и останавливается.)

Answer (score 2):

svn для этих целей подходит плохо. Он не рассчитан на бинарные файлы, обеспечивает плохое сжатие и очень тормозит при обработке большого числа файлов.

Удаление старых ревизий не предусмотрено штатными средствами, чтобы это сделать, потребуется делать дамп репозитория и чистить собственными скриптами, что довольно муторно.

Рекомендую почитать для начала это:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup

Comment: По факту ниодного верного утверждения:

1. Subversion can be used with binary files (it is automatically detected; if that detection fails, you have to mark the file binary yourself).
2. Subversion uses zlib for compressing binary differences. These diff streams are used everywhere - over the network, in the repository, and in the client's working copy.
2. Тормоза... Если вопрос стоит остро...
2. Удаление некоторых ревизий (100 первых, например):
 
    svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r101:HEAD > svn.dump
    svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
    svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < svn.dump

Comment: Возможно, что на тему плохого сжатия я погорячился, хотя опыт использования svn говорит о превышении размеров репозитория в разы от реального размера данных. В остальном остаюсь при своём мнении.

Указанный сценарий удаления ревизий будет работать очень долго уже для десятков гигабайт и требует тройного места на диске. Непонятно, зачем обрекать себя на такие сложности, когда задачу можно решить проще.

Comment: @Дож, речь о фактических ошибках, а не применимости svn для бэкапа (какого-либо). По сути, да, у cvs несколько другие задачи, тут спора нет.